# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable) not working

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I need to take all elements by `By` locator from page and determine clickable element from them.

- Screenshots for better understanding:

> Invisible element

[image: Invisible element]

> Visible and clickable element

[image: Visible and clickable element]

---

- html code with `a.quick-view` element:

  ```
  <a href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/blouses/2-7-blouse.html#/1-size-s/11-color-black" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/7-home_default/blouse.jpg" alt="" data-full-size-image-url="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/7-large_default/blouse.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="product-description">
      <h1 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/blouses/2-7-blouse.html#/1-size-s/11-color-black">Blouse</a></h1>
      <div class="product-price-and-shipping">
          <span itemprop="price" class="price">26,99&nbsp;₴</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="product-flags">
  </ul>
  <div class="highlighted-informations hidden-sm-down">

      //============================

      <a href="#" class="quick-view" data-link-action="quickview"> //Searching element 
          <i class="material-icons search"></i> Быстрый просмотр
      </a>

      //=============================

      <div class="variant-links">
          <a href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/blouses/2-8-blouse.html#/1-size-s/8-color-white" class="color" title="White" style="background-color: #ffffff"><span class="sr-only">White</span></a>
          <a href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/blouses/2-9-blouse.html#/2-size-m/11-color-black" class="color" title="Black" style="background-color: #434A54"><span class="sr-only">Black</span></a>
          <span class="js-count count"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

So, I search elements by `//a[@class='quick-view']` xpath locator and try to filter them by `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable)`:

```
public List<WebElement> getElementsIfClickable(PageElement element){
    List<WebElement> e = findAll(element);
    //e.get(0).click(); //WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="#" class="quick-view" data-link-action="quickview">...</a> is not clickable at point (534, 840)
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    return  e.stream()
            .filter(p -> isClickable(p, wait))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private boolean isClickable(WebElement element, WebDriverWait wait) {
    try {
        WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        System.out.println(el.isDisplayed()); //DEBUG: always "true"
//el.click();  //no exception
        return el.isDisplayed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, in **"DEBUG**" line I am always had true, but elemnts is not clickable and not displayed.

I do not need to cleck on each element - I just need to check clickable property.

## Question:

**How to check element by clickable property**

Comment: What exception?

Comment: @KunLun I am sorry, exception executing in other place. I did edit question

Comment: does the quick view get visible only if you move the cursor over ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by clickable property. As technically everything on the page is a clickable element. For example, you can click text but nothing will happen.
Below is the only reason an element will not be clickable is if the disabled attribute is used like so:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

Below are some links is the disabled attribute: 
[Input Disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)
[Field Disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_fieldset_disabled.asp)

However, in your case, you are referring to an anchor tag which is always clickable but may be disabled by three ways(By disabled I mean when you click it nothing happens):

1. The "href" attribute is not set
2. Disabled by css
3. href set or onclick set to return false:

```html
<a href="javascript:function() { return false; }">link</a>
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

If you still want to test if this element is clickable you could use a dirty javascript way like so:

```
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
//may need a wait here
if(url.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.getCurrentUrl())) {
        js.executeScript("window.history.go(-1);");
    }else {
        //element is not clickable
    }
```

Might not be the best solution but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

All it means to selenium to be clickable is that it is visible & enabled:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c982edfbd3eed3ffb9666c4f3e9df7c004834c22/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L632

so all you have to do is check that the webElement isDisplayed() & isEnabled().

```
    List<WebElement> webElements  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='quick-view']"));
    for (WebElement e :webElements) { 
        if (e.isDisplayed() && e.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With selenium 4 and HtmlUnitDriver this was worked for me:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(20));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).findElementById("btnRechercheAnnByDateTypeJur"))).click();
```